# Find out what caused my Ubuntu rebooting?

Tags: ubuntu, reboot

My Ubuntu 14.04 on Thinkpad T400 just rebooted automatically.

Before that,

- my screen just became unresponsive.
- My memory and swap were mostly used, mainly by webpages opened in Chrome and some pdf software.
- The cpu and hard drive didn't feel hot. At least shortly before the screen became unresponsive, their temperatures were normal (60 celcius and 40 celcius respectively).

How can I find out what caused its reboot?

Output of `less /var/log/syslog` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/syslog).

Comment: Thanks. `journalctl: command not found`

Comment: Is systemd installed?

Comment: @Jodka: `dpkg -l  |  grep -i systemd` returns  `systemd-services ` and `systemd-shim ` and some libraries.  `ps aux | grep -i systemd` returns `/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon` and `/lib/systemd/systemd-logind`.

Comment: You are right. Systemd is not part of 14.04.

Comment: @Jodka: How do you know it is not part of 14.04?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=journalctl&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any

Answer (score 2):

See `less /var/log/syslog`, `less /var/log/dmesg` and the older versions of these files. gziped backups of these files can be read with `zless`.

Comment: thanks. see my update with the output of the first command. What do you think is the cause of the reboot a little more than one hour ago?

Comment: You wifi card, but I am not sure. What is the output of `lspci`?

Comment: `lspci` output is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/lspci). My wifi card always has some problem,  but the reboot is very rare.