# Ubuntu became frozen, not responsive

Tags: ubuntu, freeze

This morning my ubuntu 14.04 has been frozen twice. The second time happened 15 or 20 mins ago. The first time is probably 2 hours ago. 
Each time, I waited for 10 mins, and nothing was improved, so I had to powered off and on.

I guess it was related to that [yesterday, my ubuntu was frozen for a short while, and then restarted itself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214016/find-out-what-caused-my-ubuntu-rebooting).

I would like to know what caused my problems, and how to solve them.
Note that: before the problem happened each time, my internal wifi card's connection was on and off. I had the wifi problems for quite some time, but never had the Ubuntu frozen problem associated with it.

My `/var/log/syslog` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/reboot/syslog)

---

Update:

```
$ cat /proc/net/igmp
Idx Device    : Count Querier   Group    Users Timer    Reporter
1   lo        :     1      V3
                010000E0     1 0:00000000       0
2   eth0      :     1      V3
                010000E0     1 0:00000000       0
5   wlan0     :     2      V3
                FB0000E0     2 0:00000000       0
                010000E0     1 0:00000000       0

$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/igmp_max_memberships
20
```

Comment: `cat /proc/net/igmp` and `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/igmp_max_memberships` could be interesting for the last messages before reboot.

Comment: updated. What are we trying to do?

Comment: With your question from yesterday, it seems, you have a bigger problem. I would start with installing a newer/another kernel and maybe a newer firmware for you wifi card. And see whether this changes something, but two reboots out of nowhere on one day and two freezes on the next out of nowhere could be even a hardware problem.